# FOP Driver Configuration same as FOPFactory

Tags: java, apache-fop

I am currently using FOP embedded using Driver as follows

```
Driver driver = new Driver();  
driver.setRenderer(Driver.RENDER_PDF);  
driver.setInputSource(new InputSource(new FileInputStream(tempout)));  
File tempFile = File.createTempFile("W2P", ".pdf");  
FileOutputStream pdfOutput = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);  
tempFile.deleteOnExit();  
driver.setOutputStream(pdfOutput);  
driver.run();
```

but i would like to have access to configuration settings programatically specifically the output resolution as I have to produce multiple resolution files 72dpi 150dpi 300dpi
the only way i can find of doing that is by changing to a FOPFactory as follows

```
FopFactory fopFactory = FopFactory.newInstance();
OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File("C:/Temp/myfile.pdf")));
Fop fop = fopFactory.newFop(MimeConstants.MIME_PDF, out);
TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(); // identity transformer
Source src = new StreamSource(new File("C:/Temp/myfile.fo"));
Result res = new SAXResult(fop.getDefaultHandler());
transformer.transform(src, res);
```

Is there a way of controling the FOP engine using Driver or will i have to switch to FOPFactory and what are the benefits/problems in doing so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Driver` class is only available in old and unmaintained versions of FOP (0.20.5 and earlier). A ["new stable API"](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/1.0/upgrading.html) (including `FopFactory`) was introduced years ago. So my advice would be to use `FopFactory` and the latest FOP (1.0).

Comment: The problem is we are using a modified version of FOP - modified to add CMYK and Spotcolor/Pantone to the PDF.  The other problem is that the previous developer who has left the company called his version 1.11.111

Comment: As far as I can tell, FOP 0.20.5 does not provide any way to access resolution settings (see http://www.stylusstudio.com/api/fop-0.20.5/index.htm). If you absolutely need this functionality, it seems like you have to bite the bullet and upgrade.

Comment: @Theresa: The original question was about Driver vs. FopFactory. I'd say that it has been answered. The fact that you use a custom version of FOP was not part of the question. If you need help sorting out additional complications, please ask a new question.