# XSL-FO static image bottom left of document, dynamic text flowing around 2 column layout?

Tags: xsl-fo, apache-fop

I am creating a PDF using dynamic XML/XSL-FO from external source,
I need an image bottom left of the page but its not working and flowing the text around the image.

The xsl used is as follows - note flower is a call to a snippet of fo:instream-foreign-object as an SVG

```
            <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
            <xsl:variable name="header" select="descendant-or-self::*[@id='prop_header']"/> 
            <xsl:variable name="title" select="substring-before($header,'-')"/>
            <xsl:variable name="price" select="substring-after($header,'-')"/>          
            <fo:block xsl:use-attribute-sets="address"><xsl:value-of select="$title"/></fo:block>
            <fo:block space-after="5mm" xsl:use-attribute-sets="innerprice"><xsl:value-of select="$price"/></fo:block>
                        <fo:block>
                <fo:float float="left" width="61mm" clip="2mm" padding="1mm"
                    border-color="$grey" border-width="0">
                    <fo:block-container padding="0pt" margin="0pt" absolute-position="absolute"  top="{$bleed + 200}mm" left="0mm" >  
                        <xsl:call-template name="flower">
                            <xsl:with-param name="width">61</xsl:with-param>
                            <xsl:with-param name="height">49</xsl:with-param>
                        </xsl:call-template>                
                    </fo:block-container>
                </fo:float>
            </fo:block>
```

The image displays at the bottom but the text is pushed to the right all the way down the page, (at 61mm - if i make the width="1mm" it works but the text overflows the image.)

How can i have the image in the correct place and the text wrap around, also the text is variable and can change so position of the image inline of the text is impossible to calculate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you use FOP, it won't work. The `fo:float` formatting object is not supported. See http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/compliance.html#fo-object-float.

Comment: We have a modded version of the older fop which my predecessor added float to it, but in the end I got the designer to change the design so I could just give the flow huge margins

Comment: @Theresa: OK, so the question is really about the behaviour of a special modded version of FOP that only you have access to. But then how can you expect anyone to give an informed answer? Something similar happened here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5042486/fop-driver-configuration-same-as-fopfactory. I think my answers to both your questions are good and reasonable, based on the available information. Please mark them as accepted. Thank you.

Comment: I was only commenting, your answer was helpful and I was able to check to see if it worked once i was told about the float however it couldnt work as required, I wish i knew the version of fop they used for the original, i have been told 0.23 but that doesnt seem right