# How to upgrading FOP 1.0 to FOP 2.4 - missing org.apache.fop.apps.Driver, org.apache.fop.messaging.MessageHandler

Tags: java, apache-fop

How can i convert this method/deprecated namespace

````
import org.apache.fop.apps.Driver;
import org.apache.fop.messaging.MessageHandler;

public static void _renderPDF(ByteArrayOutputStream out, InputSource foDocument, Logger logger)
            throws IOException, FOPException {
        Driver driver = new Driver();
        driver.setLogger(logger);
        driver.setRenderer(Driver.RENDER_PDF);
        driver.setInputSource(foDocument);
        driver.setOutputStream(out);
        driver.run();
    }```
````

Comment: There was no `Driver` class in FOP 1.0. Your code seems to be for FOP older than that. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/5052712/407651.

Comment: See https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/2.4/upgrading.html#upgrading-from-an-earlier-version-of-apache-fop

Comment: Does this answer your question? [FOP Driver Configuration same as FOPFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5042486/fop-driver-configuration-same-as-fopfactory)